# Как при деплое забирать конфиги из key/value хранилища consul и маппить в поды куба

Tags: devops, kubernetes, deploy, pod

Ищу варианты как при деплое забирать конфиги из key/value хранилища consul и маппить их в поды куба. Например, как это реализовано в vault https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/kubernetes-external-vault?in=vault/kubernetes
Но в consul такого не нашел ни в инете ни в оффициальной документации.
Аннотации которыми распологает consul не умеют прокидывать конфиги в поды, например патчем deployment.
Есть ли какие то другие решения, кроме ансибла, интересует маппинг их в, например, том
Главное то что consul - внешний сервис, а не сервис в кубе!

Comment: а вам именно нужно монтировать данные в под? обычный способ, когда приложение подключается к `consul` и получает нужную инфу, вам не подходит?

Comment: видимо вводные данные не актуальны) нашел envconsul который делает то что нужно https://github.com/hashicorp/envconsul